# Multi user calendar for website

Tags: php, html, calendar, google-calendar-api, collaboration

Here is the scenario:

I have a group of teachers teaching at the institute.
What i would like to do is develop a calender option where they can submit their available dates and times and modify them when needed.

these availability dates will then be view-able to admin on their end in calender format

these availability dates will also be view-able to the teachers on their end in calender format as well.

What would be the best way to implement such a calendar? should i try doing it in php or look for third party options like google calendar or the like?

please advise.

Comment: There are many third part services that do this already. There are probably several free/open source projects offering it so you can host it internally without sharing the organization's data with an outside party. Your Risk department or IT department should have policies and procedures covering use of external services and third party services. They will tell you what to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with you that google calendar is the way to go. But this integration hassle made me look into softalicious free software bundle being offered by my webhost. i found a multi user calendar like google calendar called "webcal" it's so far usable.. although not really fancy the way i would like it. thanks for all the help

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Google Calendar is the way to go.

Comment: Steve, the only negative aspect i see in google calendar is that, all teachers will then have to sign up for google account to create and modify these calendars. these teachers are mainly freelancers who work with many organizations and asking them to keep track of their google account is a hassle. i need something that can be operated from within the online accounts we give them

Comment: Do these teachers not have gmail accounts? Or a youtube account even? I mean by your words they're freelancers who work with many organizations, does that mean they have a different account for each organization? Would it not make more sense for them to have a more universal account like a google account (or Yahoo/Facebook/etc.) that can be used to login to multiple organizations at once? Realistically, I think managing a different account for each Org is more of a hassle.  Though I don't know what other services your oganization's account provides.

Comment: Well some of them have google accounts some don't. And they are freelance online teachers working from home with various companies. so they may have an online account with all these companies, and possibly these companies might have their own internal way of keeping track of teacher availability .. who knows..

Comment: Well, why not have them tie in their regular email account with their GMail? I get my Yahoo, website, and hotmail all to my Gmail account login.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can take a look at [wCalenar](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins/#calendar) which jquery-based multi user calendar (admin can use this to view other's calendar easily). And you have to create another field in database to save calendar settings.
2. Other case, you can create sort of OAuth login for your website. So everytime, other people can use other services like Google Calendar ( I think most of people these days have google account )
3. That's it. Have a nice day.